# How to count number of <li> tag and display it?

Tags: jquery, html

Here I want to count number of `<li>` tag and display the counted number instead of 3.

```
<ul class="nav pull-right usernav">

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span
        class="icon16 icomoon-icon-bell"></span><span class="notification">3</span> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="menu">
                <ul class="notif">
                    <li class="header"><strong>Notifications</strong> (3) items</li>

                    <li><a href="/Task_Status/get_Employee_Dialog"><span class="icon"><span class="btn_Employee_Dialog_Search select-div-icon"></span></span>
                        <span class="event">1 employee submited work</span> </a></li>

                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-user-2"></span></span>
                        <span class="event">1 User is registred</span> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-comments-4"></span>
                        </span><span class="event">Jony add 1 comment</span> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="icon"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-new"></span></span>
                        <span class="event">admin Julia added post</span> </a></li>
                    <li class="view-all"><a href="#">View all notifications <span class="icon16  icomoon-icon-arrow-right-7"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want all `li` elements? Do you want `li` elements at a specific level? Where are you getting `3` from? Some more detail and the code you've got so far would be helpful.

Comment: Please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: you can count it like $('.nav pull-right usernav li').length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.html()` method for setting the values:

```
$('.notif .header').html(function() {
   var count = $(this).siblings('li').length - 1;
   return '<strong>Notifications</strong> ('+count+') items';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kyNsr/

Edit:

```
var count = $('.notif li').length - 2;
$('.notification').text(count);
$('.notif .header').html('<strong>Notifications</strong> ('+count+') items');
```

Comment: It works, but how can it be added to..  </span><span class="notification">3</span>

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript function like this:

```
function countLi()
{
    var lis = document.body.innerHTML.match(<li>);
    return lis ? lis.length : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.header').html('('+$('span.event').length+') items)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numItems = $('.notif LI').length-2; // -2 For First & Last Li ...
        $('span.notification').html(numItems);
    });
  </script>
```

OR

If you want to count number of notifications you can use span  also like this waay

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var numItems = $('.icon').length
         $('span.notification').html(numItems);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The context of your question is not clear. Using jQuery, following will put number of 'li' inside `ul.notif`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.notification').html($('ul.notif').find('li').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length for this:

```
$('ul li').length;
```

Now if you want only to count  li elements in a specific ul, you should define that specific ul with a class or ID.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3stut/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you... :)

```
no_of_li = $('li').size();
$('.header').html('<strong>Notifications</strong> ('+no_of_li+') items');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Length` will give you the count of `li` present

```
$('.notif li').length
```

check the fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/dcLn4/)

Answer (score -1):

You can get all li object via jquery:

```
 $('li').length
```